# Is there a way to have a column overflow to the next column but still be sorted as one column in excel?

Tags: excel

So I have a big list of names and I'm trying to sort them normally A-Z. My problem is that I need to print said list on one page, but the list is too big. So I'm trying to see if there's a way to have the column overflow into the next column but still be able to be sorted as if it were one big column. I know that I could sort it in on big column and manually drag the cut off portions into their own columns but I'm sure there's a better way. Another downside to having to drag it would be that to add another name I'd have to put them all back into a column, sort, then drag every 47 rows back out.

[From this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOcyG.png)

[To this, but without manually dragging every 47 lines back up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aH9pc.png)

Comment: Alternatively, is there a way to instead keep that one big column but have it be separated into smaller columns (to fill the page) when going to print? Instead of having 1 line of a column and 3/4 of the page be blank. that would accomplish the same goal as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, done this by having a long column as the source, but the columns in the print area absolute reference 60 or 65 cells of the source column to make a neat list.

Edit, pasted 80 names into col A and the names go straight across, check your format on the cells.

Edit 2: I did the absolute references by first selecting column C down to row 80, then =A1 and ctrl+enter. Then edit : replace to replace A with $A$.

The largest to smallest sorts were done last.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This should work fine, however, is there a way to have it copy over words? When i use this method for my list of names, it inputs a "0" in the output cells.

Comment: @KNSuiteacc works fine, see edit. Check your cells format.

Comment: Yea I typed it a bit wrong heh. Thank you so much for the help! :)

Comment: @KNSuiteacc glad it helps, just think you can have the source on one sheet and the neat printing version on another if that helps.

Comment: Yea that's how I'll do it, that's exactly what I was needing :)