# How to split one column into multiple column?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to divide a particular column into Multiple columns. What do I do?

I tried many ways, but it doesn't work.

We can split the above formula output using the SPLIT function. The delimiter in the SPLIT will be the Pipe symbol. But before that, we must join all the values using a QUERY! Usually, Google Sheets users use the TEXTJOIN function here, but I am using QUERY.

Because it will work more efficiently if the number of rows to split into columns are large.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/71943930/4961700

Comment: If you are using Googlesheets then tag Googlesheets not Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Excel, as in the tag:

You can try using Delimitation, but you have to give more specific information about column content, to have more detailed solution.

Select column you would like to split and use shortcut Alt+A+E, you have to have radio button "Delimited" selected, then press Next and select character/characters you would like to split after.

For Example value:
[brass, iron, alluminium]
will be splited with this using comma (",") into three cells in three columns containing each word.
[brass] [iron] [alluminium]

But please keep in mind that you will delete content from the cells right from the selected column.

For Google Spreadsheets you can do the same, as described here:
https://zapier.com/blog/split-text-excel-zapier/